# iMacros - type text in gradually (tagging with commas)

Tags: javascript, imacros

I'm trying to automate the tagging of blog posts on my work's social network. You do this by clicking "edit tags" and then typing your tag, followed by a comma after which the tag is recognized as a tag entry. The problem is that iMacros seems to enter all of the tag and the comma literally all at once, so the comma event doesn't even get a chance to be triggered.
For what it's worth here is the code: Everything about it is right, I just need a way to overcome this problem:

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=aria-label:"Edit tags"
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT ATTR=CLASS:"js-tag-input" CONTENT={{!COL5}},
WAIT SECONDS=1
TAG POS=1 TYPE=SPAN ATTR=TXT:{{!COL5}}
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT ATTR=VALUE:"Update Tags"
```

Extra information is that when you type in the tag box, a link to the tag you're creating appears above which when clicked acts the same as typing a comma, the problem is after iMacros is finished typing it clicks outside this input field meaning that this link disappears.

Will appreciate help very much!

Comment: You need scripting with the Enterprise iMacros version.

Comment: $800 is a little out of my price range, thanks though. FMI what extra features does the enterprise version come with that justify that price? I understand it can handle more complex automation but what language does it use?